# How to find the inverse metric?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor, linear-algebra

I am trying to find the inverse of the metric

$$\mathrm ds^2 = \rho^2~\mathrm d\theta^2 -2a\sin^2\theta ~\mathrm dr~d\varphi + 2~\mathrm dr~\mathrm du + \rho^{-2}\left[\left(r^2+a^2\right)^2 -\Delta a^2\sin^2\theta\right]\sin^2\theta~\mathrm d\varphi^2-2a\rho^{-2}\left(2mr-e^2\right)\sin^2\theta~\mathrm d\varphi~\mathrm du-\left[1-\rho^{-2}\left(2mr-e^2\right)\right]~\mathrm du^2 $$

The inverse was given in [Global Structure of the Kerr Family of Gravitational Fields](http://luth2.obspm.fr/~luthier/carter/trav/Carter68.pdf) as

$$(\partial/\partial s)^2 = \rho^{-2}(\partial/\partial\theta)^2+ 2\rho^{-2}\left(r^2+ a^2\right)(\partial/\partial r)(\partial/\partial u)+ 2\rho^{-2}a(\partial/\partial r)(\partial/\partial\varphi)+ 2\rho^{-2}a(\partial/\partial u)(\partial/\partial \varphi)+ \rho^{-2}\sin^2\theta(\partial/\partial u)^2 + \rho^{-2}\sin^2\theta(\partial/\partial \varphi)^2+ \rho^{-2}\Delta(\partial/\partial r)^2$$

I know how to find the inverse of the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ but they seem to give different components to the components presented in the inverse metric. Does anyone know what method was used to find the inverse?

Comment: This is the inverse of the metric as to find the geodesics. If you read the paper carefully, you will see that the Hamiltonian of geodesics is being derived, which has the form: $H = \frac{1}{2}g^{ab} p_{a} p_{b}$, where $g^{ab}$ is the inverse metric.

Comment: Do you mean that you calculated the inverse metric and you got a different result? In this case, you should probably show us how you did it.

Comment: @IkjyotSinghKohli, What is the equation used to find the inverse metric?

Comment: @gbd Hi. Since the Kerr metric has a non-diagonal cross-term, it is slightly more complicated than the usual diagonal metric cases. However, it is a common problem, see: http://www.roma1.infn.it/teongrav/VALERIA/TEACHING/ONDE_GRAV_STELLE_BUCHINERI/AA2010_2011/LEZIONI_MIE_BH/kerr.pdf specifically after Eq. 19.10

Comment: Watch out. that Valeria writeup uses the Lindquist metric, not the same the OP is using, which is harder (less block symmetric)

Comment: @BobBee, did you try to work out any of the components of the inverse metric?  Did you get the right result?

Comment: No, see my comment below, I just put it in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's

$g_{ab}g^{bc} = \delta_a^c$

Where repeated indexes are summed, and $\delta$ is the Kronecker delta function

In abstract notation it is $g * g^{-1} = I$

Comment: What I did is I took all the components from the first metric then inserted them in a matrix and found the inverse of that matrix. Is this the correct method?

Comment: @gbd Yes. That is the common thing to do.

Comment: @IkjyotSinghKohli, I tried the method you suggested but I still get the wrong result.

Comment: @gbd okay. I will look at it a bit later when I have some more time...

Comment: I think you should explain how you inverted the matrix. There must be a mistake in what you do since there is no other way to solve your problem than actually calculate the inverse matrix.

Comment: @DelCrosB, What I did is I took all the components from the first metric then inserted them in a matrix and found the inverse of that matrix. The only correct component I got is the $g^{\theta\theta}$ component.

Comment: @gbd Careful with the computation, it's a messy metric. I'll see if I find it worked out. Did you try putting in what the answer for the inverse is supposed to be, and multiply them out and get I?

Comment: @BobBee, I have  calculated the inverse matrix using Mathematica but it looks very complicated and different to the one given.

Comment: I tried to check with Mathematica as well. I get all of the components correct except for $g_{uu}$ and $g_{\phi \phi}$. I tried to look if there is a typo like a missing $a$ somewhere but I did not find it so far. It is a bit strange. By the way did you remember to omit the factors 2 in the off-diagonal terms?

Comment: Did you get the correct $r\phi$ component?. This is what I got $-\frac{2 \rho ^2}{2 \left(a^2+r^2\right)^2+a \sin ^2(\theta ) \left(-2 a \Delta +r \text{rs}+\rho ^2\right)}$

Comment: Yes my $r\phi$ component is $\frac{2 a}{a^2 \cos (2 t)+a^2+2 r^2}$ which is correct, just written in a different way

Comment: But that is not equal to the $(\partial/\partial r)(\partial/\partial\varphi)$ component which is $2\rho^{-2}a$. Am I missing something?

Comment: It is equal. Note that $\rho$ and $\Delta$ are defined by equations (3) and (4) in the paper you are reading. Sorry by $t$ I meant $\theta$!